# Getting a seg fault but has no idea how to fix it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, debugging, segmentation-fault

The following code has a seg fault but I have really no idea how to debug it, maybe it's because my knowledge lack of C syntax, and I have read TCPL but still get nowhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    char *str[4];
    char c[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
    int find = 0;
    while (find <= 2 && *str[0] != '\0' && *str[1] != '\0') {
        if (isalpha(*str[0]) && *str[0] == *str[1]
            && *str[0] - 'A' >= 0 && *str[0] - 'A' <= 25) {
            find++;
            if (find == 1)
                c[0] = *str[0];
            else if (find == 2)
                c[1] = *str[0];
        }
        str[0]++;
        str[1]++;
    }

   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget allocated memory for string.

Your code with dynamic allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //needed for malloc and free
int main() {
    char *str[4];
    //allocate memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        //allocate 128B per string
        str[i] =(char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char)); 
        //here you should check if malloc was succesfull 
        //if malloc failed you schould free previously allocated memory
    }
    char c[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
    int find = 0;
    while (find <= 2 && *str[0] != '\0' && *str[1] != '\0') {
        if (isalpha(*str[0]) && *str[0] == *str[1]
            && *str[0] - 'A' >= 0 && *str[0] - 'A' <= 25) {
            find++;
            if (find == 1)
                c[0] = *str[0];
            else if (find == 2)
                c[1] = *str[0];
        }
        str[0]++;
        str[1]++;
    }
    //delete memory
    for (int i =0; i < 4; ++i) {
        free(str[i]);
    }
   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
char *str[4]; /* what str[0] contains ? some junk data, need to assign valid address */
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   scanf("%s", str[i]); /* No memory for str[i] here */
```

`str` is **array of character pointer** & they are uninitialized i.e not pointing any valid address. One way to solve this problem is to allocate memory for each *char pointer*, there after you can put some data into `str[i]`. For e.g

```
char *str[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   str[i] = malloc(MAX); /* define MAX value as per requirement */ 
   scanf("%s", str[i]); /* Now str[i] has valid memory */
}
```

And once job is done with dynamic memory,don't forget to free the dynamic memory by calling `free(str[i])` for each *char pointer* to avoid *memory leak*.